# tkinter Python variable.Get()

Tags: python, tkinter

When i add some text into Entry and confirm it i don't get anything like there was nothing at all i did try to look it up but i have failed , can someone plz help me it will be probably something really easy . thx

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
def press():
    win1 = Tk()
    def confirm():
        text=inp.get()+" "+inp1.get()
        print(text)
        win1.destroy()
    inp = StringVar()
    Entry(win1, textvariable=inp).pack()
    inp1 = StringVar()
    Entry(win1, textvariable=inp1).pack()
    t_okno1 = Button(win1, text='Pridaj', command=confirm)
    t_okno1.pack()

B = Button(win, text='Pridaj Tovar', command=press)
B.pack()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `win` window won't appear unless you call `mainloop` on it.

```
B = Button(win, text='Pridaj Tovar', command=press)
B.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

And `win1` should probably be a `Toplevel` instance instead of a `Tk` in order for it to properly process events.

```
def press():
    win1 = Toplevel()
```

Comment: i should have asked better i get nothing from print(text) my window will pop up fine